# discord.js Send message as code block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm trying to make a bot that will send a message to my channel, but in a code block because using RichEmbed doesn't work.

I looked some other bots and they send messages like this

````
```
  Their title
    Body text blah blah
```
````

I want to send something similar, however when I tried

````
var msg = ``` 
  Their Title
    Body text blah blah
```;
````

and

````
var msg = "```
  Their Title
    Body text blah blah
```";
````

These don't work.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const TOKEN = "MY_TOKEN_ID";

bot.on("message", function(message) {

    console.log(message.content);

    if ( message.author.equals(bot.user)) 
        return;

    message.channel.send(msg);



});

bot.login(TOKEN);
```

My code is above, any ideas how to send code blocks?

Comment: In your second example where you did `var msg " "` it doesn't have an equals sign. Is that how it is in your code or you left it out for this example.

Comment: I just left it out in the example, fixed it now.

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't very helpful. What are you expecting vs. what you're actually seeing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried using this?

````
var msg = "```Their Title\nBody text blah blah```";
````

\n is a new line, it's basically pressing ENTER when writing.
You can send it as normal text message afterward.

Comment: Thanks this works, didn't know you could add \n, thought they just would literally print \n.

Answer (score 2):

```
function codeblock(
    language:
        | "asciidoc"
        | "autohotkey"
        | "bash"
        | "coffeescript"
        | "cpp"
        | "cs"
        | "css"
        | "diff"
        | "fix"
        | "glsl"
        | "ini"
        | "json"
        | "md"
        | "ml"
        | "prolog"
        | "py"
        | "tex"
        | "xl"
        | "xml",
    code: string,
) {
    return `\`\`\`${language}\n${code}\`\`\``;
}
```

Usage

```
const msg = codeblock("css", `
#element {
    width: 500 px;
}
.button {
    width: 300 px;
}
`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of strange, but you can also do...

```
msg.channel.send( {
  content: "Please send this as a code block !",
  code: "js"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking, you can do this:

```
const { codeBlock } = require("@discordjs/builders");

<channel>.send(codeBlock("js", 'var foo = "bar";'));
```